# Unable to install ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to do full install

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284570/unable-to-install-ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-06**:
Is still a clean Ubuntu installation? Or have you had ROS and / or Gazebo installed at some point in the past?

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-03-06**:
I have the similar error for python-catkin-dkpg when I call catkin_install. I previously installed it was using smoothly.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-06**:
@tolga-uni-lu please create a new question for that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

This will offer a solution, typically it means uninstalling some stuff to get the one you need, if the tradeoff seems ok to you go for it!

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1